# Create dynamic webpages in Java

Tags: jsp

I have situation where we need to create a webpage by loading the controls dynamically depending on table source. 
The table source will be an input by User by selecting any table from the dropdown control.

I have thought to use XML to store the UI definition where the the fields, controls and properties can be a tags to configure the properties of the control for each table and store the XML in a backend table.

Read this XML depending on the selection by user on a webpage and generate webpage by populating the controls dynamically on the webpage.

The webpage also has an update and close buttons which performs their respective operations on the data.

Basically I'm looking into any stable open source framework for Java that would help me to achieve the solution, otherwise we need to do the code from scratch.

Please advise your inputs as well so that I can think over in those terms too.

Thanks in advance

PS: The Database/table in this context refers to Oracle 11g and the Java here refers to the latest version. The OS here would be Windows for Development purpose however the Pre-prod and Prod environments are Solaris 10.

Comment: [Apache Pivot](http://pivot.apache.org/) might work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert, I will take this, just have to go through the BXML stuff